# How to enable signing of SAML2 AuthNRequest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

We have a spring boot application with Saml2 configured for authentication.

We are having hard time configuring signing of Saml2 AuthNRequest, which gets rejected for that reason at IDP (which is ADFS, don't really know the version for it). We tried to disable the requirement for signing, and our application works nicely. However, this disabling was done only to test that we have everything in place.

All that is missing is now the signing of AuthNRequest. This link seems to have the same problem: [Spring Security SAML: Getting <Signature> block to appear in <AuthnRequest>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419386/spring-security-saml-getting-signature-block-to-appear-in-authnrequest). The solution for it seem to be creating `WebSSOProfileOptions` and setting the binding to `SAMLConstants.SAML2_POST_BINDING_URI`.

But there seem to be some sort of version mismatch or something. We cannot find this WebSSPProfileOptions class from our classpath at all. I'm new to all this, including gradle, but our gradle has it as a dependency like this:

```
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider -> 5.4.7
|    +--- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:3.4.6
```

I really hope there is a way to say in the configuration, that the signing is done on the AuthNRequest messages.

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          my-sp:
            decryption.credentials:
              - private-key-location: "classpath:credentials/my_private_key" 
                certificate-location: "classpath:credentials/my_cert"
            signing.credentials:
              - private-key-location: "classpath:credentials/my_private_key"
                certificate-location: "classpath:credentials/my_cert"
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: http://idp.....
              verification.credentials:
                  - certificate-location: "classpath:credentials/idp......crt"
              singlesignon:
                sign-request: true
                url: https://idp......
              metadata-uri: https://.....
```

If the signing of AuthnRequest cannot be enforced through configuration, what would be the correct way of doing it.

It feels a bit harsh to downgrade to get this WebSSPProfileOptions into classpath.
spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar seems to have it. Web page https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-saml says that it is being superseded by https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#saml2.

In short, how do we enforce signing of AuthnRequest with spring-security-saml2-service-provider version 5.4.7

Comment: The old Spring Security SAML extension project has been deprecated in favor of the `spring-security-saml2-service-provider` in Spring Security core. I didn't quite follow what exactly is your question. If you want to change the binding, you can do it by using `singlesignon.binding: "POST"`

Comment: Thanks Marcus for your effort. I tried to change this singlesignon.binding to "POST", but it only changed to HTTP method used to POST. But still, there was not signature present in the AuthnRequest. I would like to know, what exactly triggers the signing of AuthnRequest. When it fails, it would be useful to have some sort of indication of the reason... Logs maybe? But I see nothing on the logs either.

Comment: You can debug the `OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestResolver::resolve` to see how it's signing the requests. Did you already change your log level to `TRACE` in order to see the logs?

Comment: It seems that `sign-request: true` has no effect anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question, as I think we figured it out. There might also be a way to enforce signing on spring, which was really what my original question was all about.

The problem was, that spring implementation seems to be looking for `WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true"`, and it was missing in our IDP metadata.

```
  <EntityDescriptor xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        entityID="http://idp......">
    <IDPSSODescriptor xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
        protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
        WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true">
```

We managed to solve this, by downloading the IDP metadata, adding the mentioned attribute and storing the fixed metadata in a place accessible to spring. Not a perfect solution, but that's the best we can do at the moment.

Based on this finding, I believe there is a bug in either IDP or spring code. If the default value is "true", the bug is spring. If it is "false", the bug is in IDP. If the default behaviour is unspecified, then it is bad luck for everyone.

If I found out more on this subject, I will update it in here.

Comment: Any updates so far?

Answer (score 0):

In your SecurityConfig put this bean

```
@Bean
public Saml2AuthenticationRequestResolver authenticationRequestResolver(RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository registrations) {
RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver registrationResolver =
  new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(registrations);
OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver authenticationRequestResolver =
  new OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver(registrationResolver);
authenticationRequestResolver.setAuthnRequestCustomizer((context) -> context
  .getAuthnRequest().setForceAuthn(true));
return authenticationRequestResolver;
}
```